# links on rotated div with css don't seem to work

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

I display some images within rotated divs and hyperlink them. However, the links don't seem to work.... may anyone explain why that is the case?

link: http://inetgate.ca/dev/portfolio
use admin/test to get past the password prompt.

Thanks!
Ron

example code:

```
<div id="pic-7" class="pic" style="height:130px; width:110px; top:9px;left:370px; -moz-transform:rotate(-16deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(-16deg); position: absolute; background-color:#fff;background-position:center top;font-size:80%">
            <div align="center">
            <img style="margin-top:4px; border: 1px solid #999;" src="gallery/img/thumbs/wittmerperformance.png"/><a class="fancybox" rel="fncbx" href="http://www.wittmerperformance.com/" target="_blank" onclick>Wittmerperformance
            </a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You link should work; However, it seems some of your script is trying to use XHR to fetch the content from `href` while user clicks and blocking the default behavior (open the link), which causes problem, because that would be cross domain.

Comment: So, how would I go about fixing this, Passerby? Thanks! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: It's hard to tell which script causes problem, since you have so many scripts. Do you have full access to the source code, and are you the only code developer?

Comment: I have full access yes, I'm developing this page in a drupal 7 environment but have pretty much custom build the whole design template...

Comment: If you're the one that take response to the achievement, then I'm afraid you're also the one that have to track down the problems...If you really don't know what's happening, here's an _ugly_ solution: add an empty `onclick` attribute to every `<a>` inside that area.

Comment: hehe well, I'm aware of that and I do wanna figure out what is going on - so you think using the onclick eventhandler to trigger a javascript is the right way to go...? K, let me see what we can do with that... sure sounds possible... :)

Comment: Ok, so far I just trigger an alert() box on click but I want to link to another page in a new window (target="_blan" in html). How can I do this?

Comment: No, I want to use the empty `onclick` handler to **overwrite** whatever script binded to that element. Just use `<a href="..." onclick><img /></a>`. Again, this is an ugly solution, but it may help.

Comment: I've removed the link from the image and only want to apply it to the caption but it still doesn't link (even when using an empty onclick handler) - I update the code on top to display how it currently looks!

Comment: Then you really need to find out what's going on in the script/template...Some script is automatically taking charge of link behavior inside a particular area, you should check if you're using a bad framework, or using a framework in a bad manor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `position:absolute;` on the div that has the children `<a>` tag. This will fix your problem. When nesting clickable links inside an absolute positioned element, the `<a>` tag itself also has to be positioned absolute for it to be clickable, this is due to CSS priority. Why not just make the div that is `position:absolute;` to `relative` and then you wouldn't run into this issue. Or just make the `<a>` itself `absolute`. Simple fix!